# Many-to-Many relation using Mongoid database-design?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, mongoid

i try to implement the following database structure, but have problems understanding how to do so using mongoid:

I have a model **Documents**, a model **DocumentTeam** and a model **Employees**. Users can create documents and can choose employees, which get added to the DocumentTeam. This is where I'm atm:

```
class Document
  embeds_one :document_team
end

class DocumentTeam
  has_many :employees
  embedded_in :document
end

class Employee
  belongs_to :document_teams
end
```

so my question: how can i tell rails to automatically insert a chosen Employee into the the embedded DocumentTeam when creating a Document?

Furthermore I want to be able to list e.g. all briefings of a Employee by

```
Employee.first.documents
```

is this possible as well?

thanks advance!

Comment: It would be better if you can mention how briefing is related to other documents and also how do you chose the chosen employee?

Comment: see edit. pasted the wrong code!

Answer (score 1):

In mongoid you can not reference embedded documents. You can reference root documents from embedded documents, but not the other way around. i.e. you can not have `belongs_to :document_teams` in `Employee`. Also, as a side effect is that relations in embedded documents should be single sided. You can change you modeling to following to achieve what you want:

```
class Document
  embeds_one :document_team
end

class DocumentTeam
  has_and_belongs_to_many :employees, inverse_of: nil
  embedded_in :document
end

class Employee
  def documents
    Document.where('document_team.employee_ids' => self.id)
  end
end
```

This will let you use `Employee.first.documents`, but you can not treat it as a relation and  go on doing things you can do with relations, like reassigning, pushing and pulling documents. You have to manage teams and employees relations through `DocumentTeam` but can access an employees documents directly for reading.

PS: `Document` id not a good name for class, I guess it may clash with Mongoid::Document in some scenario.